# SQL to get first date and amount per account

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get back the date and amount of the first transaction per account in a transaction table. The table (GiftHeader) looks like this:

```
EntityID           Date                        Amount
1                 1/1/2027  00:00:00:00        1.00
1                 2/1/2027  00:00:00:00        2.00
2                 2/1/2027  00:00:00:00        4.00
2                 3/1/2027  00:00:00:00        2.00
```

In this case, I would expect the following:

```
EntityID          BatchDate                    Amount
1                 1/1/2027  00:00:00:00        1.00
2                 2/1/2027  00:00:00:00        4.00
```

Here's the SQL I'm using which isn't working.

```
select DISTINCT entityid, min(BatchDate) as FirstGiftDate 
from GiftHeader
group by EntityId,BatchDate
order by EntityId
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Joshua Goodwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use top 1 with ties as below

```
Select top 1 with ties * from GiftHeader
    order by row_number() over (partition by entityid order by [BatchDate])
```

Other traditional approach is

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = row_number() over (partition by entityid order by BatchDate) from GiftHeader  ) a
Where a.RowN = 1
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------------------------+--------+
| EntityId |        BatchDate        | Amount |
+----------+-------------------------+--------+
|        1 | 2027-01-01 00:00:00.000 |      1 |
|        2 | 2027-02-01 00:00:00.000 |      4 |
+----------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: SELECT
 FGD.ID,
 FGD.FirstBatchDate
FROM
 (
  SELECT
   entityid AS 'ID',
   batchdate AS 'FirstBatchDate',
   RowNum = row_number () OVER (
    partition BY entityid
    ORDER BY
     BatchDate
   )
  FROM
   GiftHeader
 ) FGD
WHERE
 FGD.RowNum = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) as follow

```sql
SELECT EntityID, 
       Date, 
       Amount 
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                 OVER ( 
                   PARTITION BY EntityID 
                   ORDER BY Date) AS RN, 
               * 
        FROM   GiftHeader) a 
WHERE  a.RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Sukru!